# ServiceController - Can't stop the service [C#]

Tags: c#, service, servicecontroller

I read many posts here with a similar question, but none helped me solve my problem.
I want to stop the service with the ServiceController object. But it fails and I get an exception: *System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005)*. I don't understand why.. I run the program with "Run as administrator".

```
ServiceController ctrl = ServiceController.GetServices().Where(s => s.ServiceName == "service_name").SingleOrDefault();
if (ctrl == null) return;

if (ctrl.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Running))
{
   try 
   {
      ctrl.Stop();
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
      Log(ex.ToString(), 3);
   }
}
```

If I call the net stop command from the code, then everything works. Why?

```
 Process cmd = new Process();
cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
cmd.Start();
cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("net stop service_name");
cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
cmd.StandardInput.Close();
cmd.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206915/discussion-on-question-by-clyde-servicecontroller-cant-stop-the-service-c).

Comment: @samuel.  Yes i tried, unfortunately clyde had low rep for me to initiate chat, may I know how its possibleb?

Comment: hi Clyde, just following up,can you confirm if the below answer helped you with your query, if yes,  please accept it by clicking the green tickbox, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After our continued chat discussion `ServiceController` following was discovered :

- `ServiceController` was able to `Start` the service, but not `Stop`
- From the System Logs it was evident that ServiceController crashes when trying to stop
- `ServiceControllers` `Start` & `Stop` works fine with other services such as `PrintSpooler`
- Using `CMD` or `Process.Start` we can stop service by `sc stop "servicename"`
- Finally the problem was with the Service itself and the way it was constructed